# Display datagrid based on one filter in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have datagrid and one value slider.I have three columns .Three columns like name,age and telephone number.Filter value is set to age.If i change slider value that is filter(age) based on filter DataGrid needs to display the data.I am using observable collection.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: *Based on value of slider datagrid need to display values* in the sense to display the columns or rows?

Comment: Just bind the slider value to the required property on the items in the collection that is bound to the DataGrid

Comment: Please be more specific in future but still i have answered. Hope that helps. No offence.

Answer (score 2):

I think i understood what you want exactly.

Assuming that the name of your Data Grid is "MyDataGrid" and it's data source is bound to a class "MyDataGridItem" with this structure

```
public class MyDataGridItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Subscribe the ValueChanged event of the slider and get the value and use LINQ where query to filter your results.

```
    private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        var sliderValue = (int) MySlider.Value;
        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = students.Where(item =>item.Age<sliderValue);           
    }
```